# How to measure Azure CosmosDB Request Units per web request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-application-insights

In an ASP.NET Core Web Application I want to measure how many request units have been spent in a single web request. With this information I could identify "expensive" calls and look for optimizing them.

I know how to option the request unit count from a single CosmosDB Rest call. But this is a layered application where the persistence level that interacts with the ComosDB does not have access to the Request-Object in ASP.NET Core.

Is there a way to optain somehow some kind of request id? I wonder how Application Insights keeps track what are dependent internal calls for a specific web request.

Or is there a way to get this information in Application Insights?

Comment: If you track metrics with the AI TelemetryClient, the operation id will be attached to them. You can then group them in AI's Analytics to get per operation stats.

Comment: Which SDK are you using? The default v2, Cosmonaut or EF Core?

Comment: @NickChapsas I use the default .net SDK. The connection mode is TCP therefore the default Application Insights dendency tracking does not work (HTTP support only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on multiple things including which SDK you are using.

If you are using the default Cosmos DB SDK also known as v2 SDK, then (assuming you enabled Application Insights support) Cosmos DB will only log it's dependency calls if you are [using HTTP/HTTPS connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies). TCP mode won't be captured by Application Insights. This means you would either have to use HTTPS which is bad in terms of performance or code something custom.

If you are using [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) then it comes out of the box with a general purpose EventSource which tracks each call as a dependency no matter the connection type and it also collects multiple metrics such as the RUs and a lot more. You would need to reference the [Cosmonaut.ApplicationInsights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cosmonaut.ApplicationInsights/) nuget package and initialise the `AppInsightsTelemetryModule` like this:

`AppInsightsTelemetryModule.Instance.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);`

or use the IoC alternative of:

`services.AddSingleton(AppInsightsTelemetryModule.Instance);`

This will give you logging for every action with detailed metrics such as the following (including the request charge):

[image]

You can then use a query like this to see spikes and further investigate, or just query for requests with Cosmos dependencies which exceed a threshold.

```
dependencies
| where type contains "Cosmos" and customDimensions.RequestCharge != ""
| summarize sum(toint(customDimensions.RequestCharge)) by bin(timestamp, 1m)
```

PS: You don't have to use the `CosmosStore` if you don't need it. Using the `CosmonautClient` instead of the `DocumentClient` will do the logging job as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the CosmonautClient.

Comment: @RalfBönning Thanks :)

Comment: @NickChapsas what are the exact differences between CosmonautClient and CosmosStore? I am more wondering to know which one to use in my scenario?

Comment: The CosmosStore is the high level class you need to be dealing with. The CosmonautClient is used by the CosmosStore to do all the necessary logging and optimisations but you shouldn't really have to deal with it.

Comment: @NickChapsas How to do it in EntityFramework core

Answer (score 0):

This is available in the CosmosDB REST API response's header. You will need to create a correlation between your web call and the CosmosDB operations and then aggregate.

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-response-headers):

> x-ms-request-charge   This is the number of normalized requests a.k.a.
>   request units (RU) for the operation. For more information, see
>   Request units in Azure Cosmos DB.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve my problem yet. I have one web request and probably multiple CosmosDB requests. I just do not know how to correlate / group them. The code where Cosmos requests are made does not have access to the issuing Request-object.

Comment: You will need to pass a correlation id and aggregate yourself, the API header provides the lowest level of grain.